# SQL Record with ID duplicating

Tags: sql

How can I only pick 1 record as it is cross-referencing"? I have many records like which has 2 lines cross referencing spouse records. I do not have any unique key for the household. all records are 2 records cross referencing each with relationship as spouse.  I only want to pick any 1 record.

```
Member1      Member2   relationship
45235455     45235460     Spouse
45235460     45235455     Spouse
56564235     56564236     Spouse
56564236     56564235     Spouse
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have reversed duplicates in all cases, then simple inequality suffices:

```
select t.*
from t
where member1 < member2;
```

If you might have missing bidirectional records, you can add another condition:

```
select t.*
from t
where member1 < member2 or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.member1 = t.member2 and
                        t2.member2 = t.member1
                 );
```

Comment: I am testing your query. I will provide an update. Thank you.

Comment: The second logic is perfect for me. It's excellent. Thank you for your prompt response.